# Запись строки из одного файла в другой php

Tags: php

Имеются два файла. В первом пять строчек, во втором четыре. Нужно из первого файла передать первую строку в конец второго файла. В первом файле эту стоку удалить. Как это сделать, не строя огромные велосипеды?

Comment: так не делается. Лучше скажите зачем это вам? почему возникла такая проблема?

Comment: Друг задачку подкинул. Думал, просто, но оказалось сложнее)

Comment: Считываете с помощью `file()` с первого файла строчки. `array_shift()` вырежет вам первую строку. Оставшийся массив через `file_put_contents()` и `implode()` пишем в первый файл. Открываем второй файл через `fopen()` в режиме добавления. Дописываем в него вырезанную строку.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь)